# prevent reloading of object tag on changing its display (style's display property)

Tags: silverlight, object, tags, visibility

I have embedded silverlight control in my html page using object tag. I have to show and hide the parent of object tag by changing the display property of the parent tag. I need to do this because the layout of the page is tabbed, i.e. user can switch between tabs. Showing a tab requires to hide the content of previous tab and show the new content.
Below is the object tag code:

```
<div id="slControlDiv" style="width:0px; height:0px;">
    <object id="slobj" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100" height="25" style="display: block;">
      <param name="source" value="ILCFileUploader.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    </object>
```

When I hide the parent of object tag, i.e change the display to none and then show it back by changing display to block or empty, silverlight control reloads.

Is there anyway to prevent its reloading? I have tried changing visibility to collapse and then to visible, but this works only in IE8 and Firefox. In other browsers the element still keeps occupying the space, although it is hidden. I want the control to release the space as well when it is hidden.

Thanks & regards,
Nadeem Ullah

Comment: Did you figure this out?
Seems like the "workaround" is too set visibility rather than display, but that's not working for me...

Comment: I think this issue isn't specific to silverlight plugins, it's occurring for me with an object element embedding some html, eg: <object data="http://example.com"></object>

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Yes, it can be handled using the visibility style property.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue and playing with visibility is not an option as I have included them within jquery-ui tabs and when the tab is not active, it sets the display to none.

Answer (score 3):

I found that setting "visibility=hidden|show" of a containing element (eg a div) allowed hiding|showing the contained object element without it reloading when re-shown. Using the "offsets" method also works (absolutely positioning it out of the visible area of the document).